How to detect collisions between objects in a centralized game script?
Consider a game script that has an array of prefabs:
[SerializeField] List<Cat> cats;

Another script in the scene has created wall objects, which are BoxCollider2D objects with the tag "Wall". In my game script, how would I detect when a cat touches a wall? I know that in the Cat script I can add a OnCollisionEnter2D function, but that script doesn't know anything about my game script. I'd like the collision logic to happen in my main game script.

Cat hits wall and calls Gamescript to tell it: I hit wall, what happens? Unity usually lets the components/ gameobject each handle what should happen. Central logic is possible but usually more used in a broader goal

As Zibelas says, you can have the cat (or the wall, if you have more cats than walls) call the GameScript's function from OnCollisionEnter2D.
If you want to avoid cats or walls having any knowledge of GameScript, you can do this via an event or delegate.
public class CollisionDelegator2D : MonoBehaviour {

    public delegate void CollisionHandler(Collision2D collision);

    CollisionHandler _handler;

    public void SetHandler(CollisionHandler handler) {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        _handler?.Invoke(collision);
    }
}

This code can be part of the cat or wall scripts, or a separate component on their prefab or even added dynamically when you spawn them. The spawning code then tells it where to delegate its collision events to:
if (instance.TryGetComponent(out CollisionDelegator2D delegator) {
    delegator.SetHandler(gameScriptInstance.HandleCatWallCollision);
}

The Collision2D object we pass through has the info about the two colliding objects, so we don't strictly need an extra argument to tell the GameScript who's calling it about a collision.
This way, only the script spawning/configuring the cats or walls needs to know about the GameScript, and the cats/walls don't have any dependency on this type. You can even pass down / inject the delegate from a higher level, if you don't want the spawning script to know about GameScript either.
